# Hints on calculating the integral $\int_0^1\frac{x^{19}-1}{\ln x}\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, logarithms, improper-integrals

I would be happy to get some hints on the following integral:
$$
\int_0^1\frac{x^{19}-1}{\ln x}\,dx
$$

Comment: Thanks `egreg` for editing. I tried but did not find any online `MathJax` editor while there are many `LaTex` ones. Hope this site be equipped with this functionality soon.

Comment: This is really similar to this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566475/

Comment: In connection with the "Feynman method" for evaluating this, my answer to [What are some good low-prerequisite examples for the heuristic advice “If you cannot prove it, prove something stronger.”?](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/2157/what-are-some-good-low-prerequisite-examples-for-the-heuristic-advice-if-you-ca/2174#2174) may be of interest.

Comment: An offline MathJax editor for Windows and Mac OS X is qute here: http://www.inkcode.net/qute. I sometimes use it for entering my math. When it looks OK, I publish it to the clipboard and paste it into stackexchange. It can be frustrating (especially when I have entered incorrect MathJax), but it works.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Let $x = e^{-y}$, we have

$$\int_0^1 \frac{x^{19} - 1}{\log x} dx = \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-\color{blue}{1}y} - e^{-\color{orange}{20}y}}{y} dy$$
This is in the form of a [Frullani's integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) and one can read off the value of the integral as

$$( \color{red}{1} - \color{green}{0} )\log\left(\frac{\color{orange}{20}}{\color{blue}{1}}\right) = \log 20
\quad\text{ since }\quad e^{-y} = \begin{cases}\color{red}{1}, &y = 0\\ \color{green}{0}, & y \to \infty\end{cases}$$

If you really need to perform the integral yourself without using Frullani's integral directly, I'll recommend you look at answers of this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/61828/59379) and learn the various proof there. 
A good exercise is translate the proof there to your particular case. This will get you familiar with the steps that need to evaluate this sort of integral.

Comment: @J.J. thanks, fixed.

Answer (score 7):

Differentiation of the integrand $$f(x,a) = \frac{x^a-1}{\log x}$$ with respect to $a$ gives $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial a} = x^a.$$  Therefore, $$I(a) = \int_{x=0}^1 f(x,a) \, dx$$ implies $$\frac{d I}{d a} = \int_{x=0}^1 x^a \, dx = \frac{1}{a+1}, \quad a > -1.$$  Integrating with respect to $a$ then yields $$I(a) = \log(a+1), \quad a > -1.$$  There are some omitted details, but this is an outline of the general solution.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the details from @heropup's answer.

Let us generalize the problem. We will evaluate
$$
\mathcal{I}(\alpha)=\int_0^1\frac{x^\alpha-1}{\ln x}\ dx\qquad;\qquad \alpha>-1.\tag1
$$
Now we apply Feynman's method (differentiate under the integral sign). Diferentiating both sides of $(1)$ yields
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial\mathcal{I}}{\partial\alpha}&=\int_0^1\frac{\partial}{\partial\alpha}\left[\frac{x^\alpha-1}{\ln x}\right]\ dx\\
\mathcal{I}'(\alpha)&=\int_0^1 x^\alpha\ dx\\
&=\left.\frac{x^{\alpha+1}}{\alpha+1}\right|_{x=0}^1\\
&=\frac{1}{\alpha+1}.\tag2
\end{align}
Integrating $(2)$ yields
\begin{align}
\mathcal{I}(\alpha)&=\int\frac{1}{\alpha+1}\ d\alpha\\
&=\ln(\alpha+1)+C.\tag3
\end{align}
In order to find out our constant of integration, we let $\alpha = 0$ so that our integrand is $0$, implying that $C = 0$. Letting $\alpha = 19$ will of course solve our original problem:
\begin{align}
\color{purple}{\int_0^1\frac{x^\alpha-1}{\ln x}\ dx}&\color{purple}{=\ln(\alpha+1)}\\
\int_0^1\frac{x^{19}-1}{\ln x}\ dx&=\large\color{blue}{\ln20}.
\end{align}

Answer (score 3):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#66f}{\large\int_{0}^{1}{x^{19} - 1 \over \ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x}&=
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x^{19} - 1}\ \overbrace{\pars{-\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{t}\,\dd t}}
^{\ds{=\ {1 \over \ln\pars{x}}}}\ \,\dd x
=\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x^{t} - x^{t + 19}}\,\dd x\,\dd t
\\[5mm]&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over t + 1} - {1 \over t + 20}}\,\dd t
=\left.\ln\pars{t + 1 \over t + 20}\right\vert_{\,t\ =\ 0}^{\,t\ \to\ \infty}
=0 - \ln\pars{1 \over 20}
\\[8mm]&
=\color{#66f}{\Large\ln\pars{20}} \approx {\tt 2.9957}
\end{align}

> In addition, you can see
>   [this method](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/566481/85343).

Answer (score 3):

You may like this method. Note
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} n(x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)=\ln x, \text{ for }x>0 $$
and hence, for $m\in\mathbb{N}$,
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1\frac{x^m-1}{\ln x}dx&=&\int_0^1\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\frac{x^i(x-1)}{\ln x}dx\\
&=&\int_0^1\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^i(x-1)}{n(x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)}dx\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\int_0^1\frac{x^i(x-1)}{n(x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)}dx\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\int_0^1x^i\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{\frac{k}{n}}dx\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{\frac{k}{n}+i}dx\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\frac{k}{n}+i+1}\\
&=&\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\int_0^1\frac{1}{x+i+1}dx\\
&=&\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\ln\frac{i+2}{i+1}\\
&=&\ln(m+1).
\end{eqnarray}
So for $m=19$, we have
$$ \int_0^1\frac{x^{19}-1}{\ln x}dx=\ln20.$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Substitute $\ln x=t$. Use integration by parts formula.

Comment: I took it as `z` and unfortunately no progress. Does taking it as `t` makes it solvable?