# Computing $\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{t}-1}{\ln x} d x$ without Feynman, where $Re(t)>-1$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Differentiating the integral w.r.t. $a$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial}{\partial a} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{a}-1}{\ln x} d x =\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{a} \ln x}{\ln x} d x 
=\left[\frac{x^{a+1}}{a+1}\right]_{0}^{1}
&=\frac{1}{a+1}
\end{aligned}
$$

Integrating both sides from $a=0$ to $a=t$ yields the result

$$
\boxed{\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{t}-1}{\ln x}dx=\ln (t+1)}
$$
where $Re(t)>-1.$

**Question**: Can it be evaluated without Feynman?

Comment: Note${\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{t}-1}{\ln x}dx=\ln |t+1|}$ is false for $t\le-1$.

Comment: yes, thank you.

Comment: $
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{t}-1}{\ln^n x}dx
$ is divergent

Comment: ... for $n\geqslant2$.

Comment: Thank you for your reminder.  The question 2 was deleted.

Comment: After $u=-\ln x$ it's a [Frullani integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frullani_integral) $\int_0^\infty\frac{f(au)-f(bu)}{u}du$ with $a:=t+1,\,b:=1,\,f(z):=1-e^{-z}$.

Comment: And if $t>-1$ you may omit the absolute value.  Probably you get a nice result if you allow $t$ complex and require $\operatorname{Re}t>-1$.  Of course then you **must** omit the absolute value.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure, we can use the dual to Feynman - turning the integral into a double integral:

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^t-1}{\log x}\:dx = \int_0^1\int_0^tx^y\:dy\:dx = \int_0^t \frac{1}{y+1}\:dy = \log(t+1)$$

by Fubini's theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Using special functions
$$I=\int\frac{x^{t}-1}{\log( x)}\,d x=\int\frac{e^{(t+1) y}}{y}\,dy-\int\frac{e^y}{y}\,dy=\text{Ei}((t+1) y)-\text{Ei}(y)=\text{Ei}((t+1) \log (x))-\text{li}(x)$$

$$\lim_{x\to 0} \, \Big[\text{Ei}((t+1) \log (x))-\text{li}(x)\Big] =0$$

$$J_k=\int_0^{e^k}\frac{x^{t}-1}{\log( x)}\,d x=\text{Ei}(k(t+1))-\text{Ei}(k)$$ The only simple case is for $k=0$
$$J_0=\frac{1}{2} \left(\log (t+1)-\log \left(\frac{1}{t+1}\right)\right)=\log(t+1)$$

Answer (score 1):

This is an answer from [Hints on calculating the integral $\int_0^1\frac{x^{19}-1}{\ln x}\,dx$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/778278/hints-on-calculating-the-integral-int-01-fracx19-1-ln-x-dx/1126599#1126599) of mine for $t=m$ an integer. Note
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} n(x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)=\ln x, \text{ for }x>0 $$
and hence, for $m\in\mathbb{N}$,
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_0^1\frac{x^m-1}{\ln x}dx&=&\int_0^1\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\frac{x^i(x-1)}{\ln x}dx\\
&=&\int_0^1\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{x^i(x-1)}{n(x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)}dx\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\int_0^1\frac{x^i(x-1)}{n(x^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)}dx\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\int_0^1x^i\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{\frac{k}{n}}dx\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\int_0^1\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}x^{\frac{k}{n}+i}dx\\
&=&\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\frac{k}{n}+i+1}\\
&=&\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\int_0^1\frac{1}{x+i+1}dx\\
&=&\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}\ln\frac{i+2}{i+1}\\
&=&\ln(m+1).
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{aligned}
\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^{t}-1}{\ln x} d x &\stackrel{x \mapsto e^{-x}}{=}  \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x t} -1}{x} e^{-x} d x \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x(t+1)}-e^{-x}}{x} d x 
\end{aligned}
$$

Using the [Frullani’s Theorem](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Frullani%27s_Integral),
we have
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{e^{-x(t+1)}-e^{-x}}{x} d x=(0-1)  \ln \left(\frac{-1}{-(t+1)}\right)=\ln (t+1)
$$