# Evaluate $\int_0^1 \frac{(x^2-1)}{\log x} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate$$\int_0^1 \frac{(x^2-1)}{\log x} dx$$

**Context:**

I came across a similar integral some time ago, and now I would like to know how to tackle this. Any hint is very welcome.

Comment: You can try Feynman's way or substitution $x=e^{-t}$ and apply Frullani's integral

Comment: See [*Integration: The Feynman Way*](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-304-undergraduate-seminar-in-discrete-mathematics-spring-2006/projects/integratnfeynman.pdf), Example 3.1, p. 3. [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566475/what-is-int-01-fracx7-1-logx-mathrm-dx) is also related.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $$f(k)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^k-1}{\log x} \mathrm{d}x$$

Then $$f'(k)=\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{x^k \log x}{\log x} \mathrm{d}x = \int_0^1 x^k \mathrm{d}x= \frac{1}{1+k} \iff f(k)-f(0)=\log(1+k) \iff f(k) = \log(1+k)$$

Evaluating $k=2$ we get $$f(2)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^2-1}{\log x} \mathrm{d}x=\log (1+2)= \log 3$$