# Prove $\int_0^1 \frac{x-1}{(x+1)\log{x}} \text{d}x = \log{\frac{\pi}{2}}$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, contour-integration, closed-form

Prove $$\int_0^1 \frac{x-1}{(x+1)\log{x}} \text{d}x = \log{\frac{\pi}{2}}$$

Tried contouring but couldn't get anywhere with a keyhole contour.

Geometric Series Expansion does not look very promising either.

Comment: tried irational function properties?

Comment: This is a mixture of rational and transcendental, I don't see how irrational functions are involved.

Comment: i see, per partes maybe?

Comment: Try to expand  $1/(1+x)$ and use [this result.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566475/what-is-int-01-fracx7-1-logx-mathrm-dx) You should get an infinite series of logarithms which is just the logarithm of a product, which you can evaluate.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Hint**. One may set
$$
f(s):=\int_0^1 \frac{x^s-1}{(x+1)\log{x}}\: \text{d}x, \quad s>-1, \tag1
$$ then one is allowed to differentiate under the integral sign, getting
$$
f'(s)=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^s}{x+1}\:dx=\frac12\psi\left(\frac{s}2+\frac12\right)-\frac12\psi\left(\frac{s}2+1\right), \quad s>-1, \tag2
$$where we have used a standard [integral representation](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.9#E16) of the digamma function.

One may recall that $\psi:=\Gamma'/\Gamma$, then integrating $(2)$, observing that $f(0)=0$, one gets

> $$
> f(s)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^s-1}{(x+1)\log{x}}\: \text{d}x=\log \left(\frac{\sqrt{\pi}\cdot\Gamma\left(\frac{s}2+1\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{s}2+\frac12\right)}\right), \quad s>-1, \tag3
> $$

from which one deduces the value of the initial integral by putting $s:=1$, recalling that 
$$
\Gamma\left(\frac12+1\right)=\frac12\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}2.
$$

*Edit. The result $(3)$ is more general than the given one.*

Answer (score 7):

We have $$I=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x-1}{\log\left(x\right)\left(x+1\right)}dx=\sum_{k\geq0}\left(-1\right)^{k}\int_{0}^{1}\frac{x^{k+1}-x^{k}}{\log\left(x\right)}dx
 $$ $$\stackrel{x=e^{-u}}{=}\sum_{k\geq0}\left(-1\right)^{k+1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-\left(k+2\right)u}-e^{-\left(k+1\right)u}}{x}du
 $$ and now we can apply the [Frullani's theorem](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html) and get $$I=\sum_{k\geq1}\left(-1\right)^{k}\log\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)=\log\left(\prod_{k\geq1}\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^{\left(-1\right)^{k}}\right)
 $$ and now note that $$\prod_{k=1}^{2N}\left(\frac{k}{k+1}\right)^{\left(-1\right)^{k}}=\prod_{k=1}^{N}\frac{2k}{2k+1}\prod_{k=1}^{N}\frac{2k}{2k-1}=\frac{\left(2N\right)!!^{2}}{\left(2N+1\right)!!\left(2N-1\right)!!}=\frac{\pi N!^{2}}{2\Gamma\left(N+\frac{1}{2}\right)\Gamma\left(N+\frac{3}{2}\right)}
 $$ where the last identity follows from the classic estimations for the [double factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html). Hence it is sufficient to take the limit as $N\rightarrow\infty
 $ and get $$I=\color{red}{\log\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)}$$ as wanted.
Maybe it is interesting to see that the we get a very famous product, known as the Wallis' product. See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wallis_product) for some proof of it.

Comment: (+1) I really like the Frullani convert you done over there as well as the manipulation of the product.

Comment: Marco, great use of [Frullani's Integral!](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807410/frullani-s-theorem-in-a-complex-context/1808847#1808847) (+1)

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\,{#1}\,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,\mathrm{Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\,\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\,\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{x - 1 \over \pars{x + 1}\ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x} & =
\int_{0}^{1}{1 \over 1 + x}\
\overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}x^{t}\,\dd t}^{\ds{x - 1 \over \ln\pars{x}}}\
\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{t} \over 1 + x}\,\dd x\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}{x^{t} - x^{t + 1} \over 1 - x^{2}}\,\dd x\,\dd t\,\,\,
\stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ x^{1/2}}{=}\,\,\,
\half\int_{0}^{1}
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{t/2 - 1/2}\,\,\, -\,\,\, x^{t/2} \over 1 - x}
\,\dd x\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\half\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{t/2} \over 1 - x}\,\,\,\dd x -
\int_{0}^{1}{1 - x^{t/2 - 1/2} \over 1 - x}\,\,\,\dd x}\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\half\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{\Psi\pars{{t \over 2} + 1} -
\Psi\pars{{t \over 2} + \half}}\,\dd t
\\[1mm] & \pars{~\Psi:\ Digamma\ Function~}
\end{align}
with the $\ds{\Psi}$ *integral representation*
$\ds{\left.\Psi\pars{z} + \gamma = \int_{0}^{1}{1 - t^{z - 1} \over 1 - t}
\,\dd t\,\right\vert_{\ \Re\pars{z}\ >\ 0}.\quad}$ $\ds{\gamma}$ is the
*Euler-Mascheroni Constant*.

---

Since $\ds{\Psi\pars{z} = \totald{\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{z}}}{z}}$:
\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{0}^{1}{x - 1 \over \pars{x + 1}\ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x} & =
\left.\ln\pars{\Gamma\pars{t/2 + 1} \over
\Gamma\pars{t/2 + 1/2}}\right\vert_{\ 0}^{\ 1}\qquad
\pars{~\Gamma:\ Gamma\ Function~}
\\[5mm] & =
\ln\pars{{\Gamma\pars{3/2} \over \Gamma\pars{1}}\,
{\Gamma\pars{1/2} \over \Gamma\pars{1}}} =
\ln\pars{\half\,\Gamma^{\, 2}\pars{\half}} = \color{#f00}{\ln\pars{\pi \over 2}}
\end{align}

> Above we used $\ds{\Gamma\pars{1} = 1}$, the $\ds{\Gamma}$-*Recursion Formula*
>   $\ds{\Gamma\pars{z + 1} = z\,\Gamma\pars{z}}$ and
>   $\ds{\Gamma\pars{\half} = \root{\pi}}$.