# How to evaluate the following integral which is improper

Tags: calculus

I want to evaluate

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{ x^n - x^m }{\ln x } d x ,\;\;\;\;\;n>0,m>0$$

My books says the answer is $\ln \left( \frac{n+1}{m+1} \right)$. however, I think this integral diverges. Notice if we apply integration by parts, then

we will have

$$ \left( \frac{ x^{n+1} }{n+1 } - \frac{ x^{m+1} }{m+1} \right)\frac{1}{\ln x} \bigg\rvert_{0^-}^{1^+} - \int ..... $$

but the first part I think diverges, so the integral diverges.

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566475/what-is-int-01-fracx7-1-logx-mathrm-dx). I'm not sure if we can call it a duplicate.

Comment: Weird.  I tried $x=e^u$, and then I got something.  Then I tried $v=\ln(u)$...

Comment: With $f(n) = \int_0^1 \frac{x^n - 1}{\ln x}{\rm d}x$ then integral you have here is $f(n) - f(m)$. The derivation of $f(n)$ is given in the link above so it's pretty close to being a duplicate.

Comment: As to the integration by parts.  If the first part diverges and the second part diverges, there is not much we can say about the sum of the two's convergence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> $\ds{\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n} - x^{m} \over \ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x:\ {\large ?}
> \,,\qquad n > 0\,,\,\,\,m>0}$.

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{1}{x^{n} - x^{m} \over \ln\pars{x}}\,\dd x & =
\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x^{n} - x^{m}}\,\,\,
\overbrace{\pars{-\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{t}\,\dd t}}
^{\ds{1 \over \ln\pars{x}}}\,\,\,\dd x =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{1}\pars{x^{m + t} - x^{n + t}}\dd x\,\dd t
\\[5mm] & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}\pars{{1 \over t + m + 1} - {1 \over t + n + 1}}\dd t =
\left.\ln\pars{t + m + 1 \over t + n + 1}
\right\vert_{\ t\ =\ 0}^{\ t\ \to\ \infty}
\\[5mm] & =
\bbx{\ds{\ln\pars{n + 1 \over m + 1}}}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

We assume $n>0,m>0$.

- The integrand being continuous over $(0,b]$, $0<b<1$, with a finite limit as $x \to 0^+$, we deduce that the only *potential* issue of convergence is near $1^-$.  Let's see how
  $\dfrac{x^n-x^m}{\ln x} $ behaves near $x=1$, $x<1$. One may write,
  by a Taylor series expansion, as $x \to 1^-$, $$ x^{n}=e^{n\ln
     x}=e^{n\ln(1-(1-
     x))}=e^{n\left[(x-1)+O((x-1)^2)\right]}=1+n(x-1)+O((x-1)^2) $$ then  $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 1^-}\frac{x-1}{\ln x}=1$ gives
  $$ \frac{x^n-x^m}{\ln x}=\frac{n(x-1)-m(x-1)+O((x-1)^2)}{\ln
     x}=(n-m)+O(x-1) $$ thus the given integral is *convergent*.
- A closed form may be obtained by observing that $$\frac{x^n-1}{\ln
     x}=n\int_{0}^{1}x^{ny} dy$$ yielding $$ \begin{align}
     \int_0^1\frac{x^n-x^m}{\ln
     x}\:dx&= \int_0^1\frac{(x^n-1)-(x^m-1)}{\ln
     x}\:dx
  \\\\&=\int_{0}^{1}dy\int_0^1(nx^{ny}-mx^{my})\:dx \\\\&=
     \int_0^1\left(\frac{n}{ny+1}-\frac{m}{my+1}\right)dy \\\\&=\ln
     \left(\frac{n+1}{m+1} \right) \end{align} $$ as expected.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{x^n-x^m}{\log(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\lim_{a\to0}\int_a^\infty\frac{e^{-(m+1)t}-e^{-(n+1)t}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{1}\\
&=\lim_{a\to0}\left(\int_a^\infty\frac{e^{-(m+1)t}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t-\int_a^\infty\frac{e^{-(n+1)t}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t\right)\tag{2}\\
&=\lim_{a\to0}\left(\int_{(m+1)a}^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t-\int_{(n+1)a}^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t\right)\tag{3}\\
&=\lim_{a\to0}\int_{(m+1)a}^{(n+1)a}\frac{e^{-t}}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{4}\\
&=\lim_{a\to0}\int_{(m+1)a}^{(n+1)a}\frac{1+O(t)}{t}\,\mathrm{d}t\tag{5}\\
&=\lim_{a\to0}\left(\log\left(\frac{n+1}{m+1}\right)+O((n-m)a)\right)\tag{6}\\[3pt]
&=\log\left(\frac{n+1}{m+1}\right)\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $x=e^{-t}$ and convert the bottom limit of integration to a limit
$(2)$: break the integral into two
$(3)$: substitute $t\mapsto t/(m+1)$ and $t\mapsto t/(n+1)$
$(4)$: combine the integrals
$(5)$: $e^{-t}=1+O(t)$
$(6)$: integrate
$(7)$: evaluate the limit