# Definite integration integration by parts

Tags: definite-integrals

> Evaluate the integral $$\int_0^1\frac{x^7-1}{\log (x)}\,dx $$

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lcK2p.jpgplz  I'm trying to solve this definite integral since 2 hours.  Please, I need help on this.

Comment: It is always better to give some idea of what you are "stuck" on.  The integrand is undefined at $x=0$, so there is a need to treat this as an improper integral.

Answer (score 1):

Note that using $\int_0^1 x^t \,dt=\frac{x-1}{\log(x)}$ we can write

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{x^7-1}{\log(x)}\,dx&=\int_0^1 (x^6+x^5+x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1)\left(\int_0^1 x^t\,dt\right)\,dx\tag 1\\\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 (x^{t+6}+x^{t+5}+x^{t+4}+x^{t+3}+x^{t+2}+x^{t+1}+x^t)\,dx\,dt\tag2 \\\\
&=\int_0^1 \left(\frac{1}{t+7}+\frac{1}{t+6}+\frac{1}{t+5}+\frac{1}{t+4}+\frac{1}{t+3}+\frac{1}{t+2}+\frac{1}{t+1}\right)\,dt\\\\
&=\log(8)
\end{align}$$

where the Fubini-Tonelli Theorem guarantees the legitimacy of interchanging the order of integration in going from $(1)$ to $(2)$.

---

Note that if we first enforce the substitution $x^7\to x$, we obtain

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \frac{x^7-1}{\log(x)}\,dx&=\int_0^1 x^{1/7-1}\left(\frac{(x-1)}{\log(x)}\right)\\\\
&=\int_0^1 x^{1/7-1}\left(\int_0^1 x^t\,dt\right)\,dx\\\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1 x^{t+1/7-1} \,dx\,dt\\\\
&=\int_0^1 \frac{1}{t+1/7}\,dt\\\\
&=\log(8)
\end{align}$$

as expected!

Comment: @hardmath Yes, I've edited accordingly.  I misinterpreted the hand-written image.

Comment: Nice approach. If you agree, I suggest that you add this as an answer to question I linked as a duplicate instead.

Comment: @projectilemotion Thank you!  I've taken your suggestion.

Comment: Yes, I gave an upvote on the answer you posted on the [linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566475/what-is-int-01-fracx7-1-logx-mathrm-dx/2369108#2369108).

Comment: @projectilemotion Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You can use feynman approach
Consider  \begin{align}
f(n)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^n-1}{\log(x)}\,dx&
\end{align}
Then
 \begin{align}
f'(n)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^n\log(x)}{\log(x)}\,dx&
\end{align}
So \begin{align}
f'(n)= \frac{1}{n+1}
\end{align}
\begin{align}
f(n)=\log(n+1)+c
\end{align}
For c \begin{align}
f(0)=0 , c=0
\end{align}
\begin{align}
f(7)=\int_0^1 \frac{x^7-1}{\log(x)}\,dx&=\log(8)
\end{align}

Comment: You might consider stating the basis for justify differentiating under the integral.

Answer (score 1):

This can be written as a [Frullani Integral](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrullanisIntegral.html):
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\frac{x^7-1}{\log(x)}\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-u}-e^{-8u}}{u}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{e^{-u}-e^{-8u}}{u}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{2}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\left[\int_\epsilon^\infty\frac{e^{-u}}{u}\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_{8\epsilon}^\infty\frac{e^{-u}}{u}\,\mathrm{d}x\right]\tag{3}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_\epsilon^{8\epsilon}\frac{e^{-u}}{u}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{4}\\
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\int_\epsilon^{8\epsilon}\frac{1+O(u)}{u}\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{5}\\[3pt]
&=\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\left(\log(8)+O(\epsilon)\right)\tag{6}\\[6pt]
&=\log(8)\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $x=e^{-u}$
$(2)$: write as a limit near $0$
$(3)$: substitute $u\mapsto\frac{u}8$
$(4)$: combine integrals
$(5)$: $e^u=1+O(u)$ for $u$ near $0$
$(6)$: integrate
$(7)$: take the limit

Comment: Rob, I had used Frullani in the solution that I posted in the "duplicate question" [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/566475/what-is-int-01-fracx7-1-logx-mathrm-dx).  So, just curious ... why not just use Frullani's result directly instead of the solid analysis that you used here?

Comment: @MarkViola: I gave the full derivation since the link in MathWorld lacks any substance. Besides it's better to give the meat of the answer here and simply cite a reference rather than give a "reference only" answer. I had actually posted the derivation before I added the reference anyway.

Comment: Yes, I developed a generalization to Frullani for complex valued functions with complex parameters [HERE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1807410/frullani-s-theorem-in-a-complex-context/1808847#1808847).  So, once equipped with this result, I feel free to simply apply the end result.  But you're right; it's always nice to embed the development and I often do so.  Other times, I cite a result.  And yet others, I take certain results for granted and apply them without explanation.  I did like your solution herein.

Answer (score 0):

**hint for the convergence**

$$f : x\mapsto \frac {x^7-1}{\log (x)} $$
is continuous at $(0,1) $ , and is locally integrable.

Near $0$, $f $ is bounded since $\lim_{0^+}f (x)=0$ thus $$\int_0^\frac 12 f (x)dx $$ is convergent.

Near $1$, $$\log (x)\sim x-1$$ and
$$\lim_{1^-}f (x)=6$$
thus $\int_\frac 12^1f (x)dx $ converges.

finally $\int_0^1f (x)dx $ is convergent.