# Calculate $\int_0^1\frac{x^9-1}{\log x}{\rm d}x$ using Beta and Gamma function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, gamma-function, beta-function

I used Wolfram to find the answer which is $\log(10)$ but can't solve no matter how hard I try.

$$\int_0^1\frac{x^9-1}{\log x}{\rm d}x$$

Comment: What've you tried *exactly*? Consider adding your own thoughts with an [edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3584401/edit).

Comment: [This old answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/899109/problems-that-become-easier-in-a-more-general-form/900398#900398) of mine might help.

Comment: See also: [What is $\int_0^1\frac{x^7-1}{\log(x)}\mathrm dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/566475/272831)

Comment: Hint: Consider
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_0^1 \int_0^1 x^{a} dx \ da.
\end{eqnarray*}

Answer (score 0):

$$I(a)=\int_{0}^{1} x^a dx=\frac{1}{1+a}.~~~~(1)$$
Integrate (1) w.r,t, $a$
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^a}{\ln x}=\ln(1+a)+C~~~(2)$$
Put $a=0$. then $$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{\ln x} dx=C~~~~(3)$$
Using (3) in (2), we get
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^a-1}{\ln x} dx=\ln(1+a)$$
Let $a=9$, to get
$$\int_{0}^{1} \frac{x^9-1}{\ln x} dx=\ln(1+9)=\ln 10$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $u=-\ln x$ so the integral is $\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-u}-e^{-10u}}{u}du$, a Frullani integral equal to $\ln10$. I'm not aware of any solution in Beta and Gamma functions, and given the form of the answer it's unclear that one should exist.